# Program received signal SIGABRT(FORTRAN)

Tags: gdb, fortran

I have problem with this code when I run inversion script.I have tried to debug with gdb:

```
Starting program: /home/milenko/fg77/f2/bin/inverse_2d
INVERSE: calculate slowness update using LSQR and regularization
open: No such file or directory
apparent state: unit 48 named stop.in
lately writing sequential formatted external IO

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x0012d422 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks as if your program has tried to write to a file called `stop.in` on unit 48 and encountered a problem.  The most probable cause of this is that that file does not exist when a WRITE statement is executed, which in turn suggests that the OPEN statement to 'attach' that file to unit 48 was not successful.

**EDIT**

Your code snippet does not show that you check the error code returned by the statement

open(48, file='stop.in', status='old')

I suggest you pop in the iostat argument and see what it tells you.

**FURTHER EDIT**

In the second sentence of my original reply replace 'does not exist' with the words 'does not exist in the location the program expects'.

Comment: write(6,335)
335   format('INVERSE: ',
     +'calculate slowness update using LSQR and regularization')
      open(50, file='nowrite', status='old', err=9999, iostat=ioflag)
9999  if(ioflag.gt.0) then
        io=0
      else
        io=51
      end if
c
      open(48, file='stop.in', status='old')
      read(48,*) iistop

Comment: @milenkomarkovic: please edit the code into your question rather than post it in comments

Comment: Maybe the write was the last success and the "open(48, file='stop.in', status='old')" failed?    This still points to the problem being that the file "stop.in" is missing.  "status=old" means that the file should already exist.   Is this file in the directory in which you are running the program?

Comment: I am running script,stop.in is created before inverse_2d.

Comment: stop.in:

This file is created and updated automatically by the inversion script and used to exit programs 
inside the inner loop over lambda under certain circumstances. The only time the user needs to deal 
with it is to run some of the codes outside of the inversion script, you will need to edit the file and 
set the value to "0".

Comment: This is from tutorial,when I debug I am in this directory /fg77/bin,and the script is /fg77.when I run the code I got:./inversion: line 79:  2682 Segmentation fault      $EXEDIR/inverse_2d